# Создать блочную матрицу вдоль 1 строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Здравстуйте, есть 5 матриц различного порядка. Необходимо создать матрицу из заданных матриц-блоков,расположив блоки вдоль 1-й строки матрицы.
Результат должен получиться таким [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю как соединить матрицы, если их сделать одной размерности, дополнив нулями. Но проблема в том, что должно получится именно так.
Существует ли какой-либо способ это сделать?

Comment: Это вы нам задание даете?

Comment: 1) Без графической иллюстрации непонятно. Результат должен быть одна строка? Нужно просто вытянуть все матрицы в одну линию, получается? 2) Что вы уже пытались сделать, с чем у вас проблема, это же просто, особенно если использовать `numpy` - есть функция `flatten`, надо применить её к каждой матрице и объединить результат

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Вообще, конечно, это свинство. Ни "здрасте", ни "пожалуйста", ни кода своего. Осталось еще в конце вопроса добавить "И быстро мне, @%я!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Определите, какой высоты и ширины должна получиться результирующая матрица
- Создайте матрицу из нулей определённых шагом ранее ширины и высоты (есть такая функция в `numpy`)
- Пройдите циклом по входным матрицам и скопируйте каждую по очереди в подходящее место выходной матрицы

Но вообще возможны варианты. Можно объединять данные горизонтально функцией `hstack`, но как это сделать для матриц разного размера - не знаю. Возможно, нужно расширить матрицы в высоту до одной высоты с заполнением нулями, а возможно как-то можно заставить `hstack` сделать это самостоятельно - тут я не в курсе, нужно смотреть, пробовать. Проверьте и такой вариант, если вам интересно.

Comment: существует ли способ это сделать не применяя цикл?

Comment: @Studene008 Ну, если вы точно знаете, что у вас ровно пять матриц не больше и не меньше, то вы можете "развернуть" цикл и просто перечислить все матрицы вручную, но это же гораздо менее удобное и не универсальное решение.

Comment: @Studene008 Может быть можно и без цикла, я дописал вопрос. Но там вы уж сами дальше копайте.